# JaxB unmarshall single primitive element

Tags: xml, jaxb, spring-batch, unmarshalling, jaxb2

I have a xml file like following

```
<tag1>
    <intag1>
        <item>
            <aaa>sdfdfsf</aaa>
            <bbb>fvdfv</bbb>
        </item>
    </intag1>
    <intag2>3</intag2>
</tag1>
```

I'm using spring batch with jaxb to read the xml and map to objects. I have a object model for `intag1` and it get mapped without any issue, but I want to map `intag2` in to a `int` object directly. Here's a sample code I've been testing, but this give me the following exception. can anyone point out the issue?

```
Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2unmarshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
jaxb2unmarshaller.setClassesToBeBound(int.class);
jaxb2unmarshaller.afterPropertiesSet();

StaxEventItemReader reader = new StaxEventItemReader();

reader.setResource(new InputStreamResource(new FileInputStream("test6.xml")));
reader.setUnmarshaller(jaxb2unmarshaller);
reader.setFragmentRootElementName("intag2");
reader.afterPropertiesSet();
reader.open(new ExecutionContext());
```

exception :

```
[com.sun.istack.internal.SAXParseException2; lineNumber: 105; columnNumber: 25; unexpected element (uri:"", local:"intag2"). Expected elements are (none)]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the lack of `javax.xml.bind.annotation` on the class `int` or `java.lang.Integer`.

**EDIT** (Removed old solution)

I managed to map only `<intag2>` by doing this :

Reader :

```
<batch:reader>
    <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemReader">
        <property name="fragmentRootElementName" value="intag2" />
        <property name="resource" value="file:config/steps/test6.xml" />
        <property name="unmarshaller">
             <bean class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
                  <property name="classesToBeBound">
                       <list>
                           <value>Intag2</value>
                       </list>
                  </property>
             </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
</batch:reader>
```

Mapping class :

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "intag2")
public class Intag2 {

    private Integer intag2;

    @XmlElement(name = "intag2")
    public Integer getIntag2() {
        return intag2;
    }

    public void setIntag2(Integer intag2) {
        this.intag2 = intag2;
    }
}
```

It looks like the root element can also be a simple element to read at the same time.

Comment: I already have model classes for mapping `intag1`, and `intag1` can be repeated for 1000+ times, that's why I'm using streaming. I don't want to map the root level `tag1` element to a java object because it'll take much more memory.

Comment: Hi @Thrax Thanks, I just posted another answer just take a quick look.

Answer (score 1):

Hi guys I found out the way to do this and posting here as an answer for others.

We need to create a model class with annotations of `RootElement` as follows and should give `@XmlValue` tag to indicate that the value of the element should map to the integer field. That's it

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "intag2")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class IV_TRAILER {

    @XmlValue
    private int value;

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```